# What is the syntax for an interface property covariant override?

Tags: c#, covariance

According to the specification [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-9.0/covariant-returns),

> **Interface Method, Property, and Indexer Override**
>
> > Adding to the kinds of members that are permitted in an interface with the addition of the DIM feature in C# 8.0, we further add support for ***override members along with covariant returns***.

I am trying to get the following covariant override to work, but I can't find an example of the syntax. Can you help?

```
public interface IFoo{}
public interface IFuzz:IFoo{}

public interface IBar
{
    IFoo Foo {get;}
}

public interface IBaz:IBar
{
    //override IFuzz IBar.Foo Foo {get;}  //This syntax isn't correct.
}
```

Maybe I am misinterpreting the specification? Help!

Comment: Why is there `IBar.Foo` in the middle of your attempted property declaration?

Comment: @SpencerBench The syntax to override an invariant interface method given a base `IFoo` and a method in `IFoo` `void M()` and given `IFuzz:IFoo` the override in `IFuzz` is `void IFoo.M()`. But that is for an invariant method override, so I attempted to apply that syntax for a covariant property override.

Comment: Yes, but overriding a property still takes the form `override TypeName PropertyName { get; set; }` or explicitly `override TypeName InterfaceName.PropertyName { get; set; }`. Spencer is right, you need to use either `IBar.Foo` or `Foo` for the property name, not both at the same time

Comment: @AndrewWilliamson Please provide a code snippet. I think you will see the "`override` keyword is not valid in this context." compiler error.

Comment: @AndrewMcClement I would say yes, but I discovered earlier that it is only draft spec as of now.

Answer (score 0):

Doh. I didn't read the specification clearly. If you come across the same issue (as of February 2022), this prefaces the above quoted section:

> ***The remainder of the draft specification below proposes a further extension to covariant returns of interface methods to be considered later.***

It doesn't exist yet.